# AWS Athena: how to use LIKE in the query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a row which has the word "cool" in "tweet" column:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets LIMIT 10
```

However, when I execute query using LIKE to find that record, nothing shows up:

```
SELECT * FROM tweeets WHERE 'tweet' LIKE '%cool%'
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Is it because I have double quote around the column name "tweet"? I tried to remove it but then I received a `COLUMN_NOT_FOUND` error.

Anything tip will be appreciated.

Comment: Your picture has single quotes around the column name. You mentioned that the column is not found when removing quotes. Have you tried double quotes? `... where "tweet" like... `

Comment: Yes I have, but it still gives me `COLUMN_NOT_FOUND` error

Comment: To get better help, I would start by replacing all images with formatted text. So you should have sample data formatted, and your query formatted.

Comment: Does this work? `Select * from tweets where tweet like '%cool%'`?

Comment: No...Still has `COLUMN_NOT_FOUND` error

Comment: Also show your DDL to confirm data type of column tweet.

Comment: `'tweet'          string`

Comment: So the single quotes are actually part of the field name? I *strongly* suggest you transform your data so that they aren't, but you should be able to use `"'tweet'" like '%cool%'` (double quotes around the quote-including field name). Single quotes in SQL are always used for literal text (which is why your original query didn't work). Double quotes can be used to escape identifiers that contain otherwise-illegal characters (such as single quotes).

Comment: And, of course, if those apparent single quotes in the field name are actually curly quotes, then you can't copy the expression that I gave you verbatim.

Comment: Can you include the raw and complete DDL into the question please?

Comment: Can you please add output of `SELECT  column_name FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tweets' ;`?